# Problem with variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch value of dropdown menu having id="childrestrictionselect" in javascript variable childrestrictid. Whats the problem with my code? Even if I try to alert msg"HI" its going well but not working for drop down menu.

```
function restrictioninsert() {
document.getElementById('childrestriction').innerHTML = "Just a second...";
var childrestrictid = encodeURI(document.getElementById("childrestrictionselect").value);
//var childrestrictid= "HI";
alert(childrestrictid);}
```

Please help I am new with JavaScript.

Respective HTML code.

```
<select id="childrestrictionselect" onchange="javascript:restrictioninsert()">
<option value="">Select Child</option>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($child)){
print '<option value="'.$result["snum"].'">'.$result["sfname"].'</option>'; }?>
</select>
```

Edited program ended after `innerHTML`. I am getting just a second message on screen.

Comment: The JavaScript looks correct to me. Could you post the HTML with the `childrestrictionselect`select element? Also what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the page to load before you can access the DOM elements:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var childrestrictid = encodeURI(document.getElementById("childrestrictionselect").value);
   //var childrestrictid= "HI";
   alert(childrestrictid);
}
```

Comment: Whats modification with that. I have already called function on change event of dropdown. My problem is variable is not getting value from  dropdown list options.

Comment: @user168415: Your code snippet does not contain any "function on change event of dropdown". Would you mind adding it to your question, so that we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: @user168415: You have 2 problems 1) `getElementById('childrestriction')` should be `getElementById('childrestrictionselect')` 2) You are removing the `option`s before getting the value, so that by the time you ask for the value, they're gone. Switch it around and it'll work: http://jsfiddle.net/2vwBK/